# Return value of a function to a function in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scope

This could possibly a duplicate of several questions out there in the SO, dostips and ss64. The research I've done point me to look out for *_scope_* in functions. but my solutions is simple and straight forward but still problem exists

1. what is really behind the `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL`
2. How `context`workd in batch scripts ex `(goto) 2>nul`
3. Why `(goto)` wrapped in braces (explained in [dostips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6491))

Here is the code i've written so far to copy file from one place to another.
My Goals were:

- Research the `scope` and `context`of batch script
- code reuse

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    goto :main

:main
    setlocal
    set _app=test
    set _base=C:/wamp64/www
    set _destination=!_base!/test
    set _source=%~dp0%/build
    set /A _flag=0

    echo *********************************************
    echo    Deploying in %~1 mode: %TIME%
    echo        Deploy path: !^_destination!
    echo *********************************************

    call :check !_base!, !_app!, _flag
    if !_flag!==0 (
        call :create !_base!, !_app!
    )
    xcopy "!_source!" "!_destination!" /D /C
    exit /b 0
    endlocal

:setbase 
    echo ::::: setting up base :::::
    chdir /D C:

    rem the base dir for app to exists=> %1
    chdir %~1 
    exit /b 0

:check 
    echo ::::: checking for local web server destination :::::
    call :setbase %~1

    set %~3= dir /p|find /C "%~2"
    exit /b 0

:create 
    echo ::::: creating the app folders :::::

    rem setting the base to create app folder %1
    call :setbase %~1
    mkdir %~2
    exit /b 0

endlocal
```

This is the output i get when i initiate `deploy.bat`

```
*********************************************
   Deploying in production mode: 19:28:53.13
       Deploy path: C:/wamp64/www/test
*********************************************
::::: checking for local web server destination :::::
::::: setting up base :::::
0
::::: creating the app folders :::::
::::: setting up base :::::
A subdirectory or file test already exists.
```

seems like the `If !_flag!`==0 which is checking whether the app folder exist in the server root and is not working at all. When i learnt the way to pass parameters to other functions; i thought it as passing a `pointer` like reference but it looks like it is deeply tied to `scope`.
So what's going on here in the code.

Comment: In `:check`, you are aren't actually running the command when you set `_flag`, you're setting that variable to the literal string. Use `for /F` to store command output in a variable.

Comment: Note that it is `%~dp0`, not `%~dp0%`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Checking for File/Dir Existence

The code you're employing to verify that a directory (?) exists is

```
set %~3= dir /p|find /C "%~2"
```

I don't think this is doing what you intend.
`SET /P` is often used like this in order to pipe the output of a command into an environment variable. (Though, you are giving `/P` to `dir`, which paginates the output—probably not what you intended.) The command you have won't do that, though. I'd guess that what this is accomplishing is setting the var to (literally) " dir /p" and then piping that through find-count. That results of `find.exe /C` never make it back into the envvar though. The output line "0" is the result of piping (nothing) through `find.exe /C`.

I propose a simpler test for existence:

```
IF EXIST "%~2" (SET /A %~3=1) ELSE (SET /A %~3=0)
```

This test worked on my Win10 machine.

I have seen some variance in how `IF EXIST` works. If you didn't want to use that, you could do it with a `FOR` loop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%e IN ('DIR /B') DO IF "%%~e"=="%~2" SET /A %~3=1
```

If you want to use the pipe in the FOR command, you'll have to escape it.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%e IN ('DIR /B ^| find /C "%~2"') DO SET /A %~3=%%~e
```

All three of these methods worked for me.

### SETLOCAL

I do not think there exists an official reference guide for cmd syntax other than the built-in help (`SETLOCAL /?`)

My experience with it is that it pushes all the envvars and working directories onto a "stack" and a corresponding `ENDLOCAL` or `EXIT` (though in scripts, you almost *always* want to use `EXIT /B`) will pop the environment off that "stack." In effect, it means that envvar/CWD changes you make in a `SETLOCAL` will only be temporary.

Comment: `though in scripts, you almost always want to use EXIT /B`. This is because if `exist /b` is not defined at the end of the function, the usual execution flow will continue which is top to bottom and can eventually be end up in a recursion with `max recursion depth reached`.

Comment: This trick `IF EXIST "%~2" (SET /A %~3=1) ELSE (SET /A %~3=0)` solved the problem.